# How to use :arg when it doesn't appers into the function scope?

Tags: python, arguments

I'm trying to use the following function, in which `:arg` doesn't, apparently, appers into the function scope.

```
class Transformer(object):

def __init__(self, mu, norm):

    self.mu = mu
    self.norm = norm

def Normalise(self, data):
    """
    Perform the normalisation (data-mu)/norm.
    --------------------------------------
    :arg
    data: data that needs to be transformed
    mu: scale
    norm: normlisation constant
    :return
    The normalized data
    """     
    return (data-self.mu)/self.norm
```

When I plug the `data` value it tells me that `mu`is undefined. However, if I define `mu`before to call the function it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to use `:arg`in this context.

Comment: looks like the docstring doesn't match the implementation. `mu` is an instance variable on whatever class this is a part of, hence the `self.mu`. It's implicitly provided by the `self` argument. Can you show the `__init__` part of this class?

Comment: @C.Nivs just didi it!

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? `:arg` is part of the comment, how exactly you expect it to affect the code?

Comment: `:arg`  and `:return` are directives for something intended to process the docstring.

Comment: It's not clear why `mu` and `norm` are mentioned at all; they should be documented by `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
tr = Transformer(mu=somevalue, norm=somevalue)
normalized = tr.Normalise(somevariable)

print(normalized)
```

Comment: what is `Normalise`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo normalise is to map all values between in interval - commonly between 0 and 1 or between -1 and 1.

Comment: yes I know what normalise is in general, I meant in your code. It is not defined...

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry, it was my mistake. I've already corrected it. Thanks